# node.js module did not self-register

Tags: javascript

before people say that i should rebuild/reinstall the node.js modules, i already did and it still apeared, however this message only appears if i use my code as following:

```
    var sections = getFiles('bot/commands');
    for (var i in sections) {
        var commands = getFiles(`${sections[i]}`);
        for (var x in commands) {
            if (commands[x].match(cmd)) {
                let cmdfile = require(`${commands[x]}/command.js`);
                cmdfile.run(client, message, args, prefix, staff);
            }
        }
    };
```

but when i just use the direct usage example:

```
 let cmdfile = require(`bot/commands/other/help/command.js`);
 cmdfile.run(client, message, args, prefix, staff);
```

it works without errors, however i do not want to use that since i need to unfold the folders containing the files and match them to the command text used, anyone know how to fix the error and make it work again?

Comment: what is getFiles?

Comment: it puts the directors of the file locations their children given as parament into a table.